# Send http request from C application in Android

Tags: android, c, http

I know there are easy ways to send http request from java application in andriod.
But I want to do the same thing by C, is it possible?

That would be great could have example for this case.

Comment: Bruh have googled this

Comment: This should be not much different than how you would do an HTTP request in any Linux system, other than your app needing the `INTERNET` permission in its manifest.

Comment: any example there? BTW, I googled, but not find any examples.